# ¿Cómo contar las veces que se repiten las palabras en una columna de dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.7, dataframe, procesamiento-de-texto

Cuento con el siguiente dataframe que contiene una columna, en la cual se encuentran letras separadas por comas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'C1':['A','A,A','C,B,A','B,C,C,A','B,A','A,C']})
```

Quisiera poder calcular frecuencia con la que se repite cada letra en un nuevo dataframe, obteniendo el siguiente resultado deseado:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'C1':['A','B','C'],
                     'Cantidad':[7,3,4]
                     })
```

Comment: Has intentando algo?, si tienes pequeño progreso, compartelo. De mi parte podrìa sugerirte hacer un bucle parecido a esto `[b for i in df['C1'] for b in i.replace(',','')]` .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Una aproximación al problema podría ser: (1) "expandir" la columna en múltiples filas mediante [stack()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas-dataframe-stack) y (2) Aplicar un [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas-dataframe-groupby) clásico para contar ahora sí las filas.

```
# Convertimos la columna en múltiples filas
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df["C1"].str.split(',', expand=True).stack(), columns=["C1"])
# Agrupamos y contamos cada grupo
new_df.groupby(["C1"])["C1"].count()

C1
A    7
B    3
C    4
Name: C1, dtype: int64
```